# Task on Bayes' law

Tags: probability

Symbols A, B, C transmits over the communication channel with probabilities $0.4;0.3;0.3$ respectively. Probability of distortion of one symbol is $0.4$ and all distortions are with equal probability. To increase reliability each symbol is transmitted 4 times. The output string is $BACB$.
What is the probability that input string was $AAAA$? $BBBB$? $CCCC$?

I have troubles with dividing this task on events...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each character #$i$ in the string, we have a receipt $R_i$ and a sent $S_i$ signal.

What do we know? $$\begin{array}{c:c:c}
\begin{array}{rl}
 \mathsf P(S_i{=}A) ~=& 0.4
\\ \mathsf P(R_i{=}A\mid S_i{=}A) ~= & 0.6 
\\ \mathsf P(R_i{=}B\mid S_i{=}A) ~= & 0.2 
\\ \mathsf P(R_i{=}C\mid S_i{=}A) ~= & 0.2 
\end{array}&\begin{array}{rl}
\mathsf P(S_i{=}B) ~=& 0.3
\\ \mathsf P(R_i{=}A\mid S_i{=}B) ~= & 0.2 
\\ \mathsf P(R_i{=}B\mid S_i{=}B) ~= & 0.6 
\\ \mathsf P(R_i{=}C\mid S_i{=}B) ~= & 0.2
\end{array}&\begin{array}{rl}
\mathsf P(S_i{=}C) ~=& 0.3
\\ \mathsf P(R_i{=}A\mid S_i{=}C) ~= & 0.2 
\\ \mathsf P(R_i{=}B\mid S_i{=}C) ~= & 0.2 
\\ \mathsf P(R_i{=}C\mid S_i{=}C) ~= & 0.6
\end{array}\end{array}$$

What do we need to know?  Since Bayes' Rule is $$~\mathsf P(S_i{=}x\mid R_i{=}y)~=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(R_i{=}y\mid S_i{=}x)~\mathsf P(S_i{=}x)}{\sum_{s} \mathsf P(R_i{=}y\mid S_i{=}s)~\mathsf P(S_i{=}s)}$$

$$\begin{array}{l:l:l}
\begin{array}{rc}
 \mathsf P(S_i{=}A\mid R_i{=}A) ~= & \frac{0.4{\cdot}0.6}{0.4{\cdot }0.6+0.3{\cdot}0.2+0.3{\cdot}0.2}
\\ \mathsf P(S_i{=}A\mid R_i{=}B) ~= & ? 
\\ \mathsf P(S_i{=}A\mid R_i{=}C) ~= & ? 
\end{array}&\begin{array}{rc}
 \mathsf P(S_i{=}A\mid R_i{=}A) ~= & ? 
\\ \mathsf P(S_i{=}A\mid R_i{=}B) ~= & ? 
\\ \mathsf P(S_i{=}A\mid R_i{=}C) ~= & ?
\end{array}&\begin{array}{rr}
 \mathsf P(S_i{=}C\mid R_i{=}A) ~= & ? 
\\ \mathsf P(S_i{=}C\mid R_i{=}B) ~= & ? 
\\ \mathsf P(S_i{=}C\mid R_i{=}C) ~= & ?
\end{array}\end{array}$$

Can you complete?

Answer (score 1):

Let P(E) denote the probability of an event 'E'.

And P(P/Q) denotes the probability of event P given event Q has occurred.

P(AAAA)=(0.4)<sup>4</sup>*N,
P(BBBB)=(0.3)<sup>4</sup>*N,
P(CCCC)=(0.3)<sup>4</sup>*N,

probability of any other signal being an input is 0.

N is a normalizing constant

Let P(D) denote the probability of distortion of a signal.


since distortion is independent of the transmission of the wave 

 P(BACB/AAAA)= (0.4)*(1-0.4)*(0.4)*(0.4),

similarly find the values of P(BACB/BBBB) and P(BACB/CCCC)
P(BACB)=P(BACB/AAAA)*P(AAAA)+P(BACB/BBBB)*P(BBBB)+P(BACB/CCCC)*P(CCCC)

now P(AAAA/BACB)=(P(BACB/AAAA)*P(AAAA))/P(BACB);

similarly find other two.